# How can I get output logged from ConEmu?

Tags: logging, conemu

I would like to know if it is possible to log all the output automatically from a session in [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io).

Specifically, I'd like to log starting bash or connecting to a remote device. I'm assuming this is possible because even with sessions to remote hosts, the output is still displayed in the ConEmu window...but maybe I am wrong.

I used to be able do it with Putty. I could start Putty, SSH to any device etc. and have all the displayed output logged in a file.

Answer (score 13):

- Logs are not enabled by default.

This setting is relatively difficult to locate.  Here's how to find it:

1. Go to **`Settings`**,

   (Click the button for it or type <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)
2. **`Features`** > **`In-console options`** (middle of dialog box)
3. select **`Log console output (*)`** and supply a path where log should go

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you didn't try to search in settings.

There is [Log console output](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsFeatures.html#id2679) option.

More information in [docs](https://conemu.github.io/en/LogFiles.html#Log_console_output) as usual.

Comment: Straight from the horses mouth, can't get much better than that.